# Div Not Clearing or Centering

Tags: css

I have this page: [food menu](http://tasteofthainh.com/index.php/our-menu/)

I have placed a clear on the dish title with the following css:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.dish: {text-align:center;}
.dishTitle {
    clear: right;
    display: block;
}
.dish img {clear: left;}
```

}

For some reason it is not clearing. If you inspect the dishTitle div it shows up and if I remove the display attribute it does clear. How can I get the images and price to be centered on a separate line below the dishNumber and dishTitle divs? Also, I have the entire dish item wrapped in the .dish div and have set it to text-align: center; but nothing is centering. I want it to look right on mobile devices and right now it just bunches everything together. Here is all of my CSS if it helps:

```
.dish {
text-align: left;
}
.dishNumber {
font-size: 18px;
display: inline;
line-height: 24px;
vertical-align: middle;
color: #FF6600;
margin-right: 2px;
}
.dishTitle {
font-size: 18px;
display: inline;
line-height: 24px;
vertical-align: middle;
color: #000066;
margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.dishPhoto {
padding-right: 8px;
padding-left: 8px;
display: inline;    
}
.dishPrice {
font-size: 18px;
clear: right;
display: inline;
float: right;
line-height: 32px;
vertical-align: middle;
color: #000066;
}
.dishDescription {
font-size: 14px;
margin-bottom: 6px;
font-style: italic;
padding-right: 44px;
}
.dish img {
max-height: 22px;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: For starters you have a semicolon after the dish class name `.dish:` ... that looks like a typo

Comment: Daniel, thanks. That centered the text when I fixed it but the image and dish title tags are still not clearing right. I will figure it out. Thanks for your help.